# Win10/Ubuntu16.04 dual boot errors

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I want to make my laptop (Acer V15 Nitro VN7-571G-50VG) dual boot Win10/Ubuntu16.04, but I got some problems. I have two disks; 1° 128GB SSD - 2° 1TB HDD. I use linux for everything but playing games, windows just for games.

When I boot the windows installer, it says:

- HDD0: 1TB HDD.
- HDD1: 128GB SSD.

so I decided to install windows in the HDD0; when finished, I've booted the ubuntu installer and there is something I don't understand, it says:

- /dev/sda : 128GB SSD.
- /dev/sdb : 1TB HDD.

They appear in a different order. So, I proceed installing ubuntu in /dev/sda (all in one partition ext4, GRUB also in sda). When it finishes and reboots, Windows 10 starts automatically without loading GRUB.

So, the questions are:

1. Why the order of the disks is different depending on the installer I boot?
2. Why is GRUB not loading, and Windows starts automatically?
3. Which disk do you recommend to install each OS in?
4. Is it good idea to install them using UEFI?
5. What partition table should have each disk (the one for linux and the one for windows)?
6. What I've to do to install them in dual boot correctly?

As extra, I've read (don't remember where) that you need to make a different partition for /boot at the install, then mount the windows EFI partition to it, but Im not that experienced and I dont know if this is true.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the order of the disks is different depending on the installer I boot?

Order is not important as UUID is used instead but depends on bus loading

> Why is GRUB not loading, and Windows starts automatically?

Grub is not in your [VBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record)

> Which disk do you recommend to install each OS in?

put both on 2x 20GB on SSD and use [lvmcache](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html) and [exfat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) on the rest.

> Is it good idea to install them using UEFI?

Sure

> What partition table should have each disk (the one for linux and the one for windows)?

GPT

> [did i] install them [for] dual boot correctly?

Install linux 2nd so windows won't remove grub.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, MBR exists only in ms-dos partition tables, not GPT right? And what is lvmcache and exfat??

Comment: @Surf3r let's call it VBR aka the first thing after bios. lvmcache makes your HDD perform like an SSD (on average)(Linux only). exfat is a file system that will work with windows and linux (NTFS and EXT4/BTRFS are not fully).